# Showing tractrix revolution is isometric to hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have a tractrix defined (in the xy plane) by the fact that the line segment formed by a tangent to the curve meeting the x axis has length 1.

Given that the tangent meets the x axis at an angle $\theta$, I'm trying to find the first fundamental form of the surface of revolution of the tractrix in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$ where $\phi$ is the rotation angle about the x axis.

It's clear that $dy/dx = -\tan(\theta)$ and $y = \sin(\theta)$. From this I can parametrise the tractrix surface of revolution by $x$ and $\phi$ however I am struggling to find a parametrisation for the surface in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to solve the differential equation to get parametric equations for the tractrix.